# paginator is not working in django

Tags: python, django

I've followed the official docs to use paginator  in Django and it not working, it shows the right page count but on every page, the whole list displayed instead of slicing it into many pages

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    current_user = request.user
    all_dress = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_active=True).order_by('-created_at')
    all_good = Item.objects.all().filter(dress_special=True)
    all_name = Name.objects.all()
    all_ads = Ads.objects.all()
    #pig
    paginator = Paginator(all_dress, 3) # Show 12 dress per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    dresss = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {
        'all_dress': all_dress,
        'all_name': all_name,
        'current_user': current_user,
        'all_good':all_good,
        'all_ads':all_ads,
        'dresss':dresss,
    }
    return render(request, 'fostan/index.html',context)
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div dir="ltr">
     <div class="pagination" align="left">
    <span class="step-links" align="left">
        {% if dresss.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first </a>
            <a href="?page={{ dresss.previous_page_number }}"> previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page number {{ dresss.number }} of {{ dresss.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
<br>
        {% if dresss.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ dresss.next_page_number }}">next </a>
            <a href="?page={{ dresss.paginator.num_pages }}">last  &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have 9 items, and I asked the paginator to show only 3 items per page, the result is 3 pages with the same 9 items on every page!

**item list**

```
  <ul class="thumbnails" >
      {% for dress in all_dress %}
    <li class="span4 pull-left" >
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a class="zoomTool" href="{% url 'dress_details' dress.pk%}" title="add to cart"><span class="icon-search"></span> عرض التفاصيل</a>
        <a  href="{% url 'dress_details' dress.pk%}"><img class="main" src="{{ dress.dress_image1.url }}" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h5> فستان  {{ dress.dress_name }} </h5>
          <h4>
              <a class="defaultBtn" href="{% url 'dress_details' dress.pk%}" title="إضفط لمشاهدة الفستان"><span class="icon-zoom-in"></span></a>

              <span class="pull-left">{{ dress.dress_price }} جنيه </span>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

      {% endfor %}

  </ul>
```

Comment: And where is the template code displaying the items ? But anyway: I'm pretty sure you're displaying items from `all_dress`, are you ?

Comment: Oh and yes - totally unrelated, but `YourModel.objects.all().filter(...)` is redundant, you should just use `YourMode.objects.filter(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice of  .filter(), yes I am using al_dress ti list the items. check the updates for the code

Comment: So you're using `all_dress` - which is the full unpaginated queryset - as source for your items, and you wonder why you have the whole queryset displayed on each page ? Maybe you should read the doc and examples more carefully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this way:

```
paginator = Paginator(all_dress, 3)
page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    dresss = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    dresss = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    dresss = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```